# Determining a linear relation via the wedge product.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The Grassmann algebra provides for an alternative of generalizing the quaternion algebra as opposed to the Clifford algebra. Here we define the wedge product $u \wedge v $.

Now there exists a particular useful theorem:

> Vectors $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_r$ are linearly dependent if,  and only if,  their wedge product vanishes,  $$u_1 \wedge u_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge  u_r = 0 \ . $$

Curiously though,  this does not give a method of finding a linear relation, given that we have linear depenedent vectors.  How would we go about using wedge products to find a linear relation between linear dependent vectors?

In an excercise I showed the following vectors $$(e_1+e_2+e_3) ,\ (e_2+e_3+e_4) ,\ (e_3+e_4+e_5) , \ (e_1+e_3+e_5)  \\ (\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5\} \text{ a basis of the underlying vector space}) $$to be linear dependent  by computing their wedge product.

Since we end up with 2-vectors cancelling each other out, I suppose we can not get a linear relation among these.

Comment: I don't se how you manage to kill $(e_1+e_2+e_3)\wedge e_4\wedge e_5$-terms. Agree with Rene, those three are independent. May be a typo or something?

Comment: I am redoing it right now. Hold on..

Comment: Denote $$u := (e_1+e_2+e_3) \wedge (e_2 +e_3 +e_4) \ , v := (e_3+e_4+e_5) \wedge (e_1 +e_3 +e_5)\ . $$ We have $$ u = e_{12}+e_{13}+e_{14}+e_{24}+e_{34} \ , \\ v = e_{13}+e_{41}+e_{43}+e_{45}+e_{51}. $$ This yields $$ u\wedge v = e_{1243}+e_{1245}+e_{1345}+e_{2431}+e_{2451}+e_{3451} = 0 \ . $$ The last identity follows by considering the permutations of the indices. So I do indeed think that the given vectors are linearly dependent, since the wedge product vanishes.

Comment: So you really have four vectors ?

Comment: Yes,  I edited. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: I was going to work out the details of my answer in your example, but its just too much work for me to compute all those wedge products.

Comment: $(e_1+e_2+e_3)-(e_2+e_3+e_4)+(e_3+e_4+e_5)=(e_1+e_3+e_5)$ so the four vectors currently shown are dependent. Now the wedge product of the four should vanish.

Comment: @robjohn But in this manner it simply amounts to blind luck at noticing such a relation in a trivial case. So we do not exactly *use* the wedge product to determine the linear relation.

Comment: Yeah. Now it's ok. When Rene (and I) made that comment one the middle two vectors was missing (as also indicated in comment that had 3-fold wedges).

Comment: @MusséRedi: that is true. You just need to keep track of the $3^4$ partial wedge products in the $\binom54$ dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

You can. Say you have $$\sum a_i v_i=0$$ then wedge with 
$u_1 \wedge \ldots \hat{v_i}\wedge  \ldots \wedge \hat{v_j} \ldots \wedge u_r$

you get 
$$a_i u_1 \wedge  \ldots \wedge \hat{v_j} \ldots \wedge u_r
+a_j u_1 \wedge \ldots \hat{v_i}\wedge   \ldots \wedge u_r=0$$
So $a_i:a_j$ is determined.

But there is some problem with your example they are not dependent.

Comment: +1: Just feel like remarking that this works only if the $r$ vectors span a space of dimension $r-1$. If the span has a lower dimension, then all those wedges involving $r-1$ vectors vanish. As they should, of course, because in that case there are two linearly independent dependency relations, so you should not be able to determine $a_i:a_j$. This is an abstraction of the method working on $n$ vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$: the determinant vanishes, iff they are dependent. You get the (ratios of) coefficients in a non-trivial dependency relation, iff one or more of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minors $\neq0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen True, I am assuming that $u_1 \wedge u_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge  u_{r-1} \neq  0$ for if they were zero then there will be a relation between the first $r-1$ vectors and you could apply my answer in a lower dimension.

Comment: What do you mean by the sum $\sum a_iv_i$ and the hatted vectors? If we wedge the whole sum with an r-vector we get more than two multivectors (each term of the  sum is wedged separately). Could you perhaps illustrate your method with my example?

Comment: I can illustrate with a different example, but it is too much work with your example. If you want to work it yourself, take the $a(e_1+e_2+e_3)+b(e_1+\dots =0$ and wedge with $(e_1+e_2+e_3)\wedge (e_2+e_3+e_4)$ and the other combinations to get the ratios of the coefficients $a:b:c:d$